# trying to connect ubuntu with windows xp using samba server

Tags: networking, server, mount, permissions, samba

I am facing the following problems when I am using samba server to share folders between Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows XP.

First, I create two folders in Ubuntu then share it to a local network by using samba share server as password protected.

For example: let me create 2 folders A, B and I also have 2 users let user1 and user2. Now I provide folder A privilege to user1 and folder B privilege to user2.

Now I go to the Windows XP Machine and access shared folders now what is happening here :

When I access folder A by user2, it has not permitted the user2 to access folder A. Then I access folder B by user2, it was permissible to user2 to access folder B, OK that's fine.

But now I go back and try to access folder A, it was allowing me to access folder A without login.

How can I manage only valid users can access their folders.

Please help me.

Thanks !